# How to override wp_insert_comment()

Tags: comments, core, pluggable

I am trying to override `wp_insert_comment()` (wp-includes/comment.php). I added the following lines of code in my `functions.php` file, located in my theme :

```
add_filter('wp_insert_comment', 'my_insert_comment');
function my_insert_comment($commentdata)
{
     /* Some stuff */
}
```

Here is a line found in the original wp_insert_comment() function :

```
function wp_insert_comment($commentdata)
{
    /* Some stuff */
    do_action('wp_insert_comment', $id, $comment);
    return $id;
}
```

After many tests, I have the feeling that the real `wp_insert_comment()` is executed, and when it comes to the `do_action()` line, my filter is taken into consideration and my `my_insert_comment()` function is finally executed.

Of course, my purpose is to replace the original function by my own one. `my_insert_comment()` is working fine if I write it directly in the `comments.php` file, but I would like to keep it *update-proof*.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Why do you want to override it?

Comment: To make some changes in the DB when a user posts a comment. That's related to specifics features I'm developing.

Comment: your hook for `wp_insert_comment` action is the best place to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override it, because this function is not pluggable and is a part of WP core. All what you can do is to add your hook for action `wp_insert_comment`, as you've actually done.

Comment: Is there any list or something of Wordpress pluggable functions ?

Comment: wp-includes/pluggable.php

Comment: Thanks. That's a pity I can't override that function... Will have to re-implement my code for each Wordpress update :/